# CRSAPKCS1v15Encryptor class not found when compiling a Symbian C++ application

Tags: c++, symbian

I have written code in symbian c++ but i faced one problem

> CRSAPKCS1v15Encryptor class was not
>   found for aes algo

and  for rsa algo in symbian

> cryptosymmetric.h cryptopadding.h file
>   not found

is there any plugin required and any other alternative for same functionality

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have some SDK installed that provides the header files and the CRSAPKCS1v15Encryptor class. Perhaps you'll need to tell your compiler the path to search for these files. Also a look at the examples and comments [here](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Asymmetric_crypto) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Info and direct link to the API package is available at: http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/AES_Encryption-Rijndael_Block_Cipher_to_Symbian_OS

Don't you know that all Symbian programming questions have their answers at http://www.forum.nokia.com ?

Comment: People can look for answers where they choose. Kindly do something about your manner, before the moderators need to take action.